# Python(Tkinter): I can't for the life of me get my widgets to show up on the window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been working on a small GUI application in python, and I just can't get the widgets to come on screen, anyone able to point out my mistakes? The program does run, however, only an empty window comes up, no widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

class application(tk.Frame):
    def _init_(self, parent):
        tk.Frame._init_(self)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.generateText()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.grid()

        self.stars = tk.StringVar()
        self.textBox = tk.Label(self, textvariable= self.stars)

        self.firstVar = tk.StringVar() 
        self.checkBox1 = tk.CheckButton(self, text='Have you finished sweeping and mopping?',
            variable=self.firstVar, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')

        self.secondVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.checkBox2 = tk.CheckButton(self, text='Have you finished preparing food?',
            variable=self.secondVar, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')

        self.thirdVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.checkBox3 = tk.CheckButton(self, text='Have you finished mowing the lawn?',
            variable=self.thirdVar, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')

        self.textBox.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.checkBox1.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.checkBox2.grid(column=1, row=2)
        self.checkBox3.grid(column=1, row=3)

    def generateText(self):
        if self.firstVar.get() is 'yes':
            self.stars.set('Here, have a gold star')

        if self.secondVar.get() is 'yes':
            self.stars.set('Nice!, have a gold star')

        if self.thirdVar.get() is 'yes':
            self.stars.set('Good job, have a gold star')

        if (self.firstVar.get() is 'yes' and self.secondVar.get() is 'yes' and self.thirdVar.get() is 'yes'):
            self.stars = 'You have 3 gold stars, what a good boy.'




app = application(None)
app.master.title('1.3 TKinter implementation')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The biggest problem is that you are using `_init_` (one underscore on each side), but it must be `__init__` (two underscores on each side)

Answer (score 1):

Read about creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I did so and with fewer distracting lines, found the multiple errors:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()

        self.stars = tk.StringVar(parent, 'something')
        self.textBox = tk.Label(self, textvariable= self.stars)
        self.textBox.grid(column=1, row=0)

app = application(root)
root.title('1.3 TKinter implementation')
root.mainloop()
```

`__init__` has two double underscores. `StringVars need to have the same parent as everything else.  Depending on default roots leads to trouble.  Apps should explicitly create exactly one root and use it for all fonts, Vars, Toplevels, and widgets put directly in root.  Then things work as expected.

Comment: fixed the code with everything you said, now im getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Julio/Desktop/project1_3.py", line 45, in <module>
    app = application(root)
  File "C:/Users/Julio/Desktop/project1_3.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.checkBox1 = tk.CheckButton(self, text='Have you finished sweeping and mopping?',
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'CheckButton'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, and a few breaks, but I finally fixed the program up. Turns out CheckButton isn't declared as `CheckButton`, it is declared as `Checkbutton` -_-

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

class application(tk.Frame):

    def genMessage(self):

        if self.firstVar.get() == 1:
            self.stars.set('You have 1 gold star')

        if self.secondVar.get() == 1:
            self.stars.set('Nice!, you have 1 gold star')

        if self.thirdVar.get() == 1:
            self.stars.set('Good job!, you have 1 gold star')

        if (self.firstVar.get() == 1 and self.secondVar.get() == 1) or (self.firstVar.get() == 1 and self.thirdVar.get() == 1) or (self.secondVar.get() == 1 and self.thirdVar.get() == 1):
            self.stars.set('Wow! You have 2 stars already!')

        if self.firstVar.get() == 1 and self.secondVar.get() == 1 and self.thirdVar.get() == 1:
            self.stars.set('You have 3 gold stars, what a good boy.')






    def createWidgets(self):
        self.starCount = 0
        self.stars = tk.StringVar(self, 'No stars yet')
        self.textBox = tk.Label(self, textvariable= self.stars)

        self.firstVar = tk.BooleanVar(self)
        self.checkBox1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Have you finished sweeping and mopping?', variable=self.firstVar, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)

        self.secondVar = tk.BooleanVar(self)
        self.checkBox2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Have you finished preparing food?', variable=self.secondVar, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)

        self.thirdVar = tk.BooleanVar(self)
        self.checkBox3 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='Have you finished mowing the lawn?', variable=self.thirdVar, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)

        self.calcBtn = tk.Button(text= 'stars?', command = self.genMessage)

        self.textBox.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.checkBox1.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.checkBox2.grid(column=1, row=2)
        self.checkBox3.grid(column=1, row=3)
        self.calcBtn.grid(column=1, row=4)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()





app = application(root)
root.mainloop()
```